Breeding of Airborne Creatures to serve as a riding mount
I am imagining a fictional world with 10% increased atmospheric density compared to earth and a surface gravity of 0.8 g. All the other relevant parameters are the same as on earth.
The humanoids who call this planet their home, are rather slim. Grown male individuals would weigh an average of 35 kg if they stood on a scale on the surface.

According to my research, in the above mentioned conditions, airborne creatures had to use less energy to perform flying maneuvers due to the lower gravity.

Flying animals would grow bigger.

Flying creatures had more lift due to increased atmospheric density.

Even though the lower gravity may promote less developed muscular structures in their wings, breeding, feeding and training measures performed by the local humanoids could also lead to stronger muscles and therefore to better flying and carrying abilities.


My Question is: Would it be possible to breed certain species of the local airborne fauna,so that they will be specialized in carrying heavier weights, and maybe even carry these humanoids through the air?

James Cameron already wrote Avatar and we all loved it without checking the math

It is obviously possible if the story teller wants it to be possible. I cannot even think of a story featuring dragon riders where anybody bothers with aerodynamical calculations.

"According to my research, in the above mentioned conditions, airborne creatures had to use less energy to perform flying maneuvers due to the lower gravity." yes and no. They would have an easier time to get up in the air due to reduced gravity. However the denser atmosphere would increase drag. Especially at higher speeds the additional drag should have a high impact. So, creatures can fly into the air easier but flying fast would be actually more difficult than on earth. For nodedive maneuvers both changes would actually be detrimental leading to MUCH lower top speeds.

This doesn't quite work under Earth conditions but you made it easier by reducing gravity, increasing atmospheric density and reducing weight. Are you looking for some maths to see whether you adjustments are big enough?

I would appreciate that, thank you :)


Would it be possible to breed certain species of the local airborne fauna,so that they will be specialized in carrying heavier weights

Sure, we breed birds for different reasons such as size and fighting abilities.
But they may have evolved that big on their own anyway. We've had flying creatures on Earth quite capable of carrying 35kg loads. The Haast Eagle of New Zealand is thought to have been capable of that. So if it was actually bred for it and trained it should be manageable.

Is that an Laden or Unladen Haast Eagle. Held underneath the dorsal guiding feathers...

It would have to be unladen to carry the 35kg load, you wouldn't describe it's carrying capacity if it's already laden with the weight of a coconut.
